# Objective C: Improve the Brush Texture

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-graphics

I am trying to make a Brush/Paint Application for iPad for me to be more familiar with Objective-C and be fluent with it. Now, i already have a basic coloring app and i want to improve its texture to something similar to [Zen Brush](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/zen-brush/id382200873?mt=8). I want it to have a more brush-like feel when the user starts to paint.

How will i able to do that?

Here's the code for the drawing part of my app:

```
    currentTouch = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    currentTouch.y -= 20;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    [touchDraw.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, touchDraw.frame.size.width, touchDraw.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 25.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), redAmt, greenAmt, blueAmt, alpha);
    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), endingPoint.x, endingPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentTouch.x, currentTouch.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    touchDraw.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    
    endingPoint = currentTouch;
    
    touchMoved++;
    
    if (touchMoved == 10) {
        touchMoved = 0;
    }
```

It's a preparation for my school project that will end on the 30th.

Thanks!

Comment: I doubt there's anything in the iOS API that would let you make textured lines in a straightforward fashion – Zen Brush probably paints lines using custom code to achieve the effect.

Comment: awwww! thanks! i'll just find another way to improve my brush texture.

Comment: how about using an image for the texture?? can i do that?

Comment: I suppose you could try the painting by repeatedly drawing a semi-transparent image of your brush texture between the start point and the end point, but I've no idea how exactly to do it so it looks "nice" or even if it's the right approach.